# onclick event don´t works in mobile devices

Tags: jquery, onclick, onclicklistener, ontouch

I use this simple code for when click in div, check input checked, and also change color when i do click over div

**My code :**

```
  <div class="container_item" onclick="$('.check_<?php echo $pd;?>').attr('checked','checked');$('.drop_container_item').removeClass('drop_click');$(this).addClass('drop_click');">Test Click</div>
```

The problem it´s in all browsers works, but in mobile device don´t works, for example when i use un mobile devices, change the color of div, but don´t works the check

**You can test here :**

https://jsfiddle.net/aqnz3vc9/

I try other posibilities but i haven´t luck about this ways, thank´s in advanced for the help, regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you shouldn't use inline event handler as they are very outdated and no longer best practice.

As you're using jQuery attach your event handlers unobtrusively. If you use `on()` you can hook to both the `click` and `touch` events which will then work for desktop and mobile devices. Try this:

```html
<div class="drop_container_item">Click Now</div>
<input type="radio" class="check" name="veritas" value="yes">
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.drop_container_item').on('click touch', function() {
    $('.check').prop('checked', true);
    $('.drop_container_item').removeClass('drop_click');
    $(this).addClass('drop_click')
  });
});
```

Comment: Really very strange the problem really was use attr for get checked in mobile device don´t works but yes , works use prop, really strange, but thank´s for your help the problem finally no onclick the problem wa use attr, regards ! :)

Comment: Glad it worked, but the advice is still sound; don't use `onclick`.